# How can I serialize a picture with Json-serializer?

Tags: json.net

How can I serialize a picture with Jason-serializer?
I have a class that one property of this class is picture and for WCF Serilization I need to serialize this object with jason serializer, but it is not possible to do that.

Comment: Did you use a `System.Drawing.Image` or `System.Drawing.Bitmap` or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) serializes byte arrays as base64 encoded text.

Comment: Could you elaborate with type `System.Drawing.Image`?

Answer (score 1):

Use this way of returning Stream (from [WCF RAW programming](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2008/04/17/wcf-raw-programming-model-web.aspx))

```
[OperationContract, WebGet]
public Stream GetTestImage(Image image)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    image.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    stream.Position = 0;
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
    return stream;
}
```